# How to use lvm directly on tmpfs?

Tags: linux, lvm, tmpfs

LVM can use devices as backing store for physical volumes
but not directories.

tmpfs can be mounted at any mountpoint but mountpoints are always
directories.

How can the two be reconciled?

I’m aware of the roundabout solution of creating a file on the tmpfs
first, binding it to a loop device, and then using that as the
store. However that implies using a resource (loop devs) that is not
namespaced and thus shared across containers. When isolation is a
concern, this approach is not an option.

What other options are there on a sufficiently recent Linux system?

Comment: Have you considered using a ramdisk? Also, isn't it possible to choose which devices are available in a container? That would make it possible to exclude the loop devices. https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=7012396

Comment: As for ramdisks, ``CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM=y`` (though that could be worked around). Regarding loop devices, they seem to leak out of the container onto the host. Not immediately but after a while.